# Renaming file on SFTP server with WinSCP .NET assembly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Following error is coming when trying to move the file from one folder (upload folder) to another (archive) which is available on SFTP server using WinSCP .NET assembly in PowerShell:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Attendance Integration\Scripts\Power Shell 
 Script\Download&MoveToArchive.ps1:28 char:5
+     $Sftp.RenameRemoteFile($existingFilepath,$newFilepath)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Following is the code which I am using to transfer the file:

```
# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$existingFilepath = "/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv"
$newFilepath = "/Archive/attendance v2-201709220930.csv"

# Transfer files
$session.GetFiles($existingFilepath,"C:\Transfer Files\Attendance Files\*").Check()

$Sftp.RenameRemoteFile($existingFilepath,$newFilepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Session.MoveFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_movefile):

```
$session.MoveFile($existingFilepath, $newFilepath)
```

---

Your code does not make any sense:

```
$Sftp.RenameRemoteFile($existingFilepath,$newFilepath)
```

- There's no `$sftp` variable in your code
- [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session) does not have any `RenameRemoteFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *assignment* of `$Sftp`.

Comment: Where i am missing the assignment of     '$Sftp' ?

Comment: I don't see it anywhere. Im not familiar with sftp but you need to assign `$Sftp` somewhere before you can invoke `RenameRemoteFile`